# Finding "dots" or foci in images with low contrast

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have stained cells with an antibody and I am interested in counting the number of foci or "dots" per cell. The image below is from channel 1
[image]
and represents nucleus of the cell and only regions within this disk shaped objects are of interest.

The image below, for the same view as above but for a separate channel that stains small disk shaped regions or "dots"

[image]

I hope that you can see dots, some of high intensity and some of low intensity. I am trying to count these using matlab (image processing toolbox) but I have not been successful.

This is what I have so far

```
 filenameDAPI='https://i.stack.imgur.com/urJ3W.png';
 DAPI=imread(filenameDAPI); % nuclei
 nuclei_bin=imfill(im2bw(DAPI,graythresh(DAPI)),'holes');
 nuclei_bin=bwareaopen(nuclei_bin,2000); % filter out small regions
 filenameTRITC='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4He.jpg';

 TRITC=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4He.jpg'); % dots

 Th=graythresh(TRITC); % threshold that finds nuclei
 Th2=graythresh(TRITC(TRITC>Th)); % threshold that finds foci
 FOCI=im2bw(TRITC,Th2);

 % now filter FOCI by size
 minArea=2; maxArea=200; % threshold to remove spurious foci
 FOCI_labeled=bwlabel(FOCI,8);
 FOCI_props=regionprops(FOCI_labeled,TRITC,'Area'); 
 A=[FOCI_props.Area];
 keepIndices=find(A >= minArea & A <= maxArea);
 FOCI_mask=ismember(FOCI_labeled,keepIndices);
 FOCIfiltered=FOCI.*FOCI_mask; 

 outline_FOCI=bwperim(FOCIfiltered);
 overlay_FOCI=imoverlay(TRITC,outline_FOCI,[1 .1 .3]);

 subplot(2,2,1); imshow(TRITC); 
 subplot(2,2,2); imhist(TRITC)
 subplot(2,2,3); imshow(FOCIfiltered);
 subplot(2,2,4); imshow(overlay_FOCI)
```

And the resulting picture is shown here:
[image]
Unfortunately, the result shown in subplot (2,2,4) is not so good--many real dots are missed while spurious dots are identified.

I would be grateful if  someone can help me improve the dots.

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple local maximum filter for you (3X3 region):

```
filenameTRITC='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4He.jpg';
TRITC=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4He.jpg'); % dots
TI=TRITC; 
TRITC=double(TRITC);
TRITC=TRITC.*(TRITC>100);
TRITC=TRITC.*(TRITC<254); % Please note there are several parts in which the signals are saturated, I did not consider the local maximum of them
[xx yy]=size(TRITC);
[x y]=find(TRITC(2:xx-2,2:yy-2));
px=[];py=[];
x=x+1;y=y+1;
for i=1:length(y)-1
   flag=1;
   for j=-1:1
      for k=-1:1
         if TRITC(x(i)+j,y(i)+k)>TRITC(x(i),y(i))
            flag=0;
            break;
        end
      end
   end
   if flag==1
      px=[px y(i)];py=[py x(i)];
   end
end


figure,
imagesc(TI); 
hold on
plot(px,py,'r.')
```

I selected a region, zooming in, to show you the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In exactly the same spirit as lennon310, Matlab has some tools to quickly find local extrema.

```
im = imread('');
% Threshold, values under it are not accepted as extrema.
thresh = 120;
% Region of interest to determine an extrema in. 
roi = 5;
% Gray scale dilation to find local maxima
local_extr = ordfilt2(im, roi^2, ones(roi)); 
% Get local maxima and reject candidates below a threshold
result = (im == local_extr) & (im > thresh);
% Get indices of extrema
[r, c] = find(result);
% Show them
figure;imshow(im, []); hold on;
plot(c, r, 'ro');
```

[image]