# Image Analysis: Finding proteins in an image

Tags: python, image-processing, imagej

I am attempting to write a program that will automatically locate a protein in an image, this will ultimately be used to differentiate between two proteins of different heights that are present. [image: proteins in a membrane]

The white area on top of the background is a membrane in which the proteins sit and the white blobs that are present are the proteins. The proteins have two lobes hence they appear in pairs (actually one protein).

I have been writing a script in Fiji (Jython) to try and locate the proteins so we can work out the height from the local background. This so far involves applying an adaptive histogram equalisation and then subtracting the background with a rolling ball of radius 10 pixels. After that I have been applying a kernel of sorts which is 10 pixels by 10 pixels and works out the average of the 5 centre pixels and divides it by the average of the pixels on the 4 edges of the kernel to get a ratio. if the ratio is above a certain value then it is a candidate.

the output I got was this image which apart from some wrapping and sensitivity (ratio=2.0) issues seems to be ok. My questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach or is there an obviously better way of doing this?
2. Can you suggest a way on from here? I am a little stuck now and not really sure how to proceed.

[image]

code if necessary: http://pastebin.com/D45LNJCu

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: This should be moved to: https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think @Maurits gave a good approach. You could also consider doing deconvolution on your source image beforehand, to make the segmentation even easier, since it would clarify the image.

Comment: @karlphillip Really? Then most of the questions on this site tagged with "imagej" should be moved as well. I would disagree, though: the [on topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that "specific programming problems" and "software tools commonly used by programmers" are fair game.

Comment: @ctrueden It's just my opinion :) I don't expect others to agree with me. This sounds more like an image processing research problem than a programming problem. I'm only suggesting this because I think the guys at DSP could help him better.

Comment: You need to share the source code inside the question, instead of referring to an external site.

Comment: By the way, it's a good time to commit to [Computer Vision](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision). and ask some questions to help set the tone of the site.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise, I associate signal processing more with electronics. And sorry about not putting the code inside the post, I thought it was getting long enough already without an extra load of lines.

Comment: @Samuel Barnett The DSP community is both talented and helpful. By all means, post the question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about starting off a bit more simple and using the Harris-point approach and detect local maxima. Eg.

```
import numpy as np
import Image
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

roi = 2.5
peak_threshold = 120

im = Image.open('Q766c.png');
image = im.copy()

size = 2 * roi + 1
image_max = ndimage.maximum_filter(image, size=size, mode='constant')
mask = (image == image_max)
image *= mask

# Remove the image borders
image[:size] = 0
image[-size:] = 0
image[:, :size] = 0
image[:, -size:] = 0

# Find peaks
image_t = (image > peak_threshold) * 1

# get coordinates of peaks
f = np.transpose(image_t.nonzero())

# Show
img = plt.imshow(np.asarray(im))
plt.plot(f[:, 1], f[:, 0], 'o', markeredgewidth=0.45, markeredgecolor='b', markerfacecolor='None')

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('local_max.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer! Totally impressive. I [filed an issue for the ImageJ OPS project](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-ops/issues/77) to support this sort of segmentation as well.

Comment: Thanks that is a much nicer approach! I have been trying to get your code to run but I am running into this error:     image *= mask
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'Image' and 'bool'
is it to do with one of the modules? I installed the scipy-stack for python 3.4

Comment: @Samuel Barnett, honestly, I have no idea, I am still on python 2.7 via Macports. If it is any help I did the same trick with Matlab [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334589/finding-dots-or-foci-in-images-with-low-contrast/20363000#20363000).

Comment: @Maurits, yes that did help! I have managed to get it working in Matlab so hopefully it will take of from now. Thank you for your help! might end up posting it in DSP if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 3):

ImageJ "Find maxima" does also similar.

[image: ImageJ Find Maxima]

Here is the Jython code

```
from ij import ImagePlus, IJ, Prefs
from ij.plugin import RGBStackMerge
from ij.process import ImageProcessor, ImageConverter
from ij.plugin.filter import Binary, MaximumFinder
from jarray import array

# define background is black (0)
Prefs.blackBackground = True

# find maxima
#imp = IJ.getImage()
imp = ImagePlus('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q766c.png')
ImageConverter(imp).convertToGray8() 
ip = imp.getProcessor()
segip = MaximumFinder().findMaxima( ip, 10, 200, MaximumFinder.SINGLE_POINTS , False, False)

# display detection result
binner = Binary()
binner.setup("dilate", None)
binner.run(segip)
segimp = ImagePlus("seg", segip)
mergeimp = RGBStackMerge.mergeChannels(array([segimp, imp, None, None, None, None, None], ImagePlus), True)
mergeimp.show()
```

**EDIT:** Updated the code to allow processing PNG image (RGB), and directly loading image from this thread. See comments for more details.

Comment: I have been trying to run this code but have been come across an error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DirectColorModel cannot be cast to java.awt.image.IndexColorModel

Any ideas?

Comment: @SamuelBarnett  Sorry for that. The PNG image is in RGB format so I modified the code to directly load image at the top of this page and also to convert it to 8-bit grayscale by `ImageConverter(imp).convertToGray8()`. Please try.

Comment: The `from jarray import array` seems not necessary. For me simply `mergeimp = RGBStackMerge.mergeChannels([segimp, imp, None, None, None, None, None], True)` works fine.